# Play sound on android

Tags: android, audio

```
package gal.doron.ballinthehole;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;

public class Bricks 
{
    Brick[][] bricks;
    public Bricks(int rows, int cols, float brickW, float brickH)
    {
        bricks = new Brick[rows][cols];
        float x=0,y=0;
        for(int i=0;i<rows;i++,y+=brickH)
        {
            x=0;
            for(int j=0;j<cols;j++,x+=brickW)
            {
                bricks[i][j] = new Brick(x, y, brickW, brickH, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean isHitAll()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<rows();i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<cols();j++)
            {
                if(bricks[i][j].getType()!=0 && bricks[i][j].getType()!=4)
                    return false;
            }
        }
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.hopa);
        mp.start();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Hello everyone, Can you help me to play a sound (in my case the sound cal "hopa") when the function that called 'isHitAll()' is true  (When all the bricks was hit)?

this is my try.. and i get the error  in this line "MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.hopa); "
"The method crate(Context, int) in the type MediaPlayer is not applicable for the arguments (Brick,int)".

Sorry for my English and thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You get the error `The method crate(Context, int) in the type MediaPlayer is not applicable for the arguments (Brick,int)`. Because you cannot pass an object of type "`Brick`" where `Context` is needed. Since `Brick` is not and does not extend or implement Activity there is no way for it to references the current `Activity`'s `Context`.

A possible solution would be to add a `Context` field to your `Brick` class and then use a `Getter`/`Setter` to set the `Context` field in your `MainActivity`'s `OnCreate`. Then you want to construct the MediaPlayer with that `Context` field.

Example:

```
package gal.doron.ballinthehole;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
Context context;
public class Bricks 

{
    Brick[][] bricks;
    public Bricks(int rows, int cols, float brickW, float brickH)
    {
    bricks = new Brick[rows][cols];
    float x=0,y=0;
    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++,y+=brickH)
    {
        x=0;
        for(int j=0;j<cols;j++,x+=brickW)
        {
            bricks[i][j] = new Brick(x, y, brickW, brickH, 1);
        }
    }
}

public boolean isHitAll()
{
    for(int i=0;i<rows();i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<cols();j++)
        {
            if(bricks[i][j].getType()!=0 && bricks[i][j].getType()!=4)
                return false;
        }
    }
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.hopa);
    mp.start();
    return true;
}

 public void setContext(Context context){
 this.context = context;
}
public Context getContext(Context context){
  return this.context;
}
```

}

in your `MainActivity`

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Brick.setContext(getContext());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MediaPlayer needs an Activity's context in order to be created. It is helpful to create a class that extends Application and store an application context in a public static variable there. You could also just pass the Activity's context into 'Bricks' class constructor like so:

**Edit:** since you're not calling this class from an activity, you should try creating a new class called MyApplication or something and declare it as follows:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    public static Context context;

    onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();


        context = getApplicationContext();

    }

}
```

**Edit:** Then in Bricks, use the Application context when you create the MediaPlayer.

```
  public class Bricks 
  {

  MediaPlayer mp;

  Brick[][] bricks;
  public Bricks(int rows, int cols, float brickW, float brickH)
  {

      mp = MediaPlayer.create(MyApplication.context, R.raw.hopa);
      bricks = new Brick[rows][cols];
      float x=0,y=0;
      for(int i=0;i<rows;i++,y+=brickH)
      {
          x=0;
          for(int j=0;j<cols;j++,x+=brickW)
          {
              bricks[i][j] = new Brick(x, y, brickW, brickH, 1);
          }
      }
  }

  public boolean isHitAll()
  {
      for(int i=0;i<rows();i++)
      {
          for(int j=0;j<cols();j++)
          {
              if(bricks[i][j].getType()!=0 && bricks[i][j].getType()!=4)
                  return false;
          }
      }

      mp.start();
      return true;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you please include your MainActivity's code? Or whatever class is calling Bricks = new Bricks(...)? Also the error you're getting if possible?

Comment: Try declaring MediaPlayer earlier in the code, then creating it in the constructor. Please see the edited code now. Are you getting the same error?